# Changing state of checkbox with button tag no longer works

Tags: html, css, checkbox

up until recently the following code snippet has worked fine, the checkbox itself is hidden by CSS, and clicking on the button changed the state of the checkbox, which can then be detected upon form submit, however, recently (not sure when) this stopped working, and now the click of the button does nothing:

```
<label for="someCheckBox" class="someCheckBox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="someCheckBox" name="someCheckBox" value="checkBox" />
    <button type="button" title="Some CheckBox">Some CheckBox</button>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
#someCol label.someCheckBox button {
    background-color: black;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 10px 4px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    -moz-border-radius: .75em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .75em;
    border-radius: .75em;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-family:"Final Frontier";
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 40px;
}
#someCol label.someCheckBox button:hover {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #606060;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-name: glow;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: glow;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
#someCol label.someCheckBox input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
#someCol label.someCheckBox input:checked + button {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #606060;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #C0C0C0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #C0C0C0;
}
#someCol label.someCheckBox button {
    width: 90px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 4px;
}
```

It should be noted that I briefly tried updating one of these button/checkboxes to be a text label instead of a button, and the checkbox state did change as expected, however, I wanted the buttons for the look of the form, and I have many of these in place so it would take a lot of work to change them all...

likewise I preferred this approach originally because it reduced the need for JS making the forms more HTML only friendly, so although I can write a script to change the state of the checkbox, it doesn't serve my underlying purpose, and again it would take a lot of work to correct all the buttons set up this way when this worked previously.

since this did work previously and I've not touched the codebase for sometime, I'm not sure what changed other than browsers updating, can anyone assist as I've been tearing my hair out for hours now, and cannot figure out what changed...

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get an answer, so went with the easiest alternative which was to add a JS onClick event.  It's not how I wanted it to work, but was the quickest solution:

```
<label for="someCheckBox" class="someCheckBox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="someCheckBox" name="someCheckBox" value="checkBox" />
    <button type="button" title="Some CheckBox" onclick="changeStateButton(\'someCheckBox\',\'check\');">Some CheckBox</button>
</label>

function changeStateButton(selID,selType){
    if (document.getElementById(selID) !== null && document.getElementById(selID) !== "undefined"){
        if (selType="check"){
            if (!document.getElementById(selID).checked) {
                document.getElementById(selID).checked = "checked";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(selID).checked = "";
            }
        } else if (selType="radio"){
            if (!document.getElementById(selID).checked) {
                document.getElementById(selID).checked = "checked";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can answer why it stopped working the pure HTML way I'd still be interested to hear.

Comment: I saw this question earlier this week and then, as now couldn't fathom how the original version would have worked in the first place. Was it a magical copy and paste from somewhere, or could you explain how it did work? A couple of points with the solution you've got now - you don't need to test the state of a radio button - if it's not checked, you check it, but there's no reverse action. So, just check it if it's a radio. Next, you've got 7 instances of using getElementById - just call it once at the top of the func and assign the result to a variable. Also, no need to escape `'`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented seem overly complex and verbose. I'd be inclined to take advantage of the fact that the elements concerned are both UI elements and as such, respond to mouse events.

I'd also consider making the code smarter so that it doesn't need the inline JS to attach the button to its targeted input element. Perhaps by way of an attribute that holds the id of the target, or better yet - you could get the parent of the clicked button (the label) and then get the (only) input element that it contains and perform the action on it.

To go about it in the first manner that I describe, you can call the `click()` function of the target element and be done with it in 3 lines, like so:

```
function myChange(tgtId)
{
    var tgtElem = byId(tgtId);
    if (tgtElem != undefined)
        tgtElem.click();
}
```

This function is a drop-in replacement for the one you have already and also makes your html neater and less prone to error too, removing the need to pass a second variable. Though it will still need to be attached via inline javascript.

Perhaps a neater solution would be to write a handler that can work out which element the button is paired with, by virtue of the fact that they're the only siblings of the same parent. It also means that you could setup an arbitrary number of them in a very small loop, again keeping your html cleaner.

So first, the function that does the checking/unchecking.

```
function myChange2(evt)
{
    var clickedButton = this;
    var containingLabel = clickedButton.parentNode;
    var tgtElem = containingLabel.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (tgtElem != undefined)
        tgtElem.click();
}
```

We find out which element cause the function to be called, get it's parent and then get the first element in the list of buttons that it contains (there should only be one, but the function returns a list, a NodeList to be specific). We then simply click the element, allowing the browser to handle the change of state.

Finally, we need a way to connect the function to all of the elements that will need it. We'll make use of querySelectorAll, since it allows us to use css selectors, which greatly simplifies the process of getting the list of elements that we're actually interested in. I've used the `>` character to signify that the element needs to be a direct child of the label - it wont target a button contained in another element that is itself contained in the label. (You can see this in effect in the first checkbox I've added, by wrapping a button in a span which is inside the label.) We'll then attach the event, which gives us access to the `this` keyword in the handler function, which allows the code to know which button caused it to be invoked.

Here's a complete example - I've changed the class of the labels so that attaching the event to the ones I've added wont interfere with the one that's already there. I've also removed the `type='button'` attribute from each button - you only need this attribute if you're using an input (of type button). I've also removed the `value` attribute from the checkbox, since it is either checked or unchecked - the browser handles this for us. The radio-button needs it, but the checkbox doesn't.

About my remark in the comments section regarding escaping of the `'` character - you can wrap a single quote in double quotes, or the other way around. You only need to escape a quote when it's enclosed by quotes of the same type.

So, without escaping with a slash - `'"'` is okay, as is `"'"`.
You'd just need it for `'''` or `"""`, which would each become `'\''` and `"\""`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    var elemsToInit = document.querySelectorAll('label.btnProxy > button');
    var i, n = elemsToInit.length;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        elemsToInit[i].addEventListener('click', myChange2, false);
    }
}

function myChange(tgtId, tgtType)
{
    var tgtElem = byId(tgtId);
    if (tgtElem != undefined)
        tgtElem.click();
}

function myChange2(evt)
{
    var clickedButton = this;
    var containingLabel = clickedButton.parentNode;
    var tgtElem = containingLabel.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (tgtElem != undefined)
        tgtElem.click();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="someCheckBox" class="someCheckBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="someCheckBox" name="someCheckBox" value="checkBox" />
        <button type="button" title="Some CheckBox" onclick="myChange('someCheckBox','check');">Some CheckBox</button>
    </label>

    <hr>

    <label class="btnProxy"><input type="checkbox"/><button>Toggle</button><span><button>I'm Inert!</button></span></label>
    <br>
    <label class="btnProxy"><input type="checkbox"/><button>Toggle</button><button>I work too!</button></label>
    <br>
    <label class="btnProxy"><input type="checkbox"/><button>Toggle</button></label>

    <hr>

    <label class="btnProxy"><input type="radio" name='gender' value='alien'/><button>Select</button></label>
    <br>
    <label class="btnProxy"><input type="radio" name='gender' value='female'/><button>Select</button></label>
    <br>
    <label class="btnProxy"><input type="radio" name='gender' value='male'/><button>Select</button></label>

</body>
</html>
```